# Definition of $\ell^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, notation, definition

I have come across the space of bounded sequences denoted as $\ell^\infty$ in my course, but not a clear, concise definition. I have seen sometimes when these includes sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ that are bounded and sometimes when the sequence is in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$! So I presume this implies $\ell^\infty$ for is bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i guess this can be generalised in metric spaces as well). Also it will be great if someone could mention a clear definition of $\ell^0$ and $\ell^1$ as my lecturer didnt do so.

Thanks

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space $\ell^\infty$ is the Banach space given by
$$\ell^\infty = \{f\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|\ \|f\|_\infty<\infty\}$$
where
$$\|f\|_\infty = \sup_n |f_n|$$
The definition for $\ell^p$, $1\leq p<\infty$ is similar, only using the norm
$$\|f\|_p=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty|f_n|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
I don't know of any $\ell^0$ space.

Comment: The $l^0$ space (at least, the way it was defined for us), is the sequence space of "eventually zero" sequences, which is usually equipped with the uniform norm.

Comment: @AndrewD Ah, I see. I usually call it $c_0$.

Comment: I get the feeling that there isn't a standard definition for it, seeing as the wikipedia page defines $c_0$ as the sequence space of sequences with limit 0, whereas the "eventually zero" definition means that every sequence is the space is *finite* with limit 0.

Comment: in regards to the metric for l^infinity, i take it the rhs is the usual/euclidean metric?

Comment: @Raul Yes, it is.

Comment: @Raul In the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$- and $\mathbb{C}^n$-valued sequences, yes.

Comment: another quick query, can we also use the discrete metric? it seems to me you can but it seems like this metric comes with this space like a definition. thanks

Comment: @Raul You need a norm to define those spaces, not a metric.

Comment: ok that makes sense but my lecturer came up with a counter example that BW doesn't hold in any metric space, in particular he used l^infinity and considered Xn={1,1,,,,1,0...,0} where 1 occurs n times and then z={0,0,....0}, he then wrote d(Xn,z)=1, how did he get this?

Comment: @Raul The metric in $\ell^\infty$ is induced by the norm, i.e. $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$. Btw please try to use LaTeX to use your questions/comments more readable.

Comment: sorry, i havent learn how to use latex yet, btw using that norm, I dont get d(Xn,Z)=1 for all n in the naturals.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11772/discussion-between-daniel-robert-nicoud-and-raul)

Comment: i dont think the chat is working for me for some odd reason?